# Image with clickable components

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc, dynamic-image-generation

I have an image that displays a parking lot. I want to make parking slots clickable and connect them with records in salesforce using lwc. Leaflet-rastercoords seems a good tool to achieve this but I have difficulty in implementing it in lwc with VScode. Anyone has tackled a similar task?

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be done in HTML with an Image-Map. That also supports the use of Javascript functions.
I'm not sure how LWC in Salesforce works with HTML, but maybe you can use it in there?
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp

Comment: My problem is more salesforce-oriented, I can only import this image as a Static Resource and then it's non-editable. Any solution regarding this?

Comment: This guy seems to have been able to make it work. He made a clickable map using images in Salesforce Lightning. Wish I could help more, but I don't have Salesforce to fiddle around in... <https://salesforcecodex.com/salesforce/dynamic-image-map-in-salesforce-lightning/>

Comment: It's a nice example anyway thank you for your time.